# Is it possible to start a fragment a new fragment activity after a button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Just a small question, maybe hard, maybe not.
But just like the title says, is it possible to start a new fragmentActivity after a button pressed?

Now I have been researching this on my own and I rather not start a new activity again, unless I have to ofcourse.
So far I am happy with my results, as I try to make three different fragment packages in one class for 3 different buttons I have.

Thus for short, There are 3 buttons and they need to activate their own Fragment Package.

Here's my current code I want try to fix:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       /* viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter padater = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(padater);*/
    }

    public boolean contentSwitch = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(contentSwitch) {
            finish();
            Log.i("BtnHandleEvent", "BackButton Pressed!");
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            contentSwitch = false;
        } else {
            Log.i("Event Handler", "Terminating app!");
            Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalization(); //No idea why I did this
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();              //No idea why I did this too
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);           //Doesn't cleanup?
        }
    }

    //start fragment activity
    public void btn1(View v) {
        contentSwitch = true;
    }

    public void btn2(View v) {
        contentSwitch = true;
    }

    public void btn3(View v) {
        contentSwitch = true;

    }}
```

FragmentPackage:

```
public class FragmentPackage extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public static boolean ViewPackOne = false; //Still to do

    //Still need to fix
    public FragmentPackage(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch(arg0) {
            case 0:
                if(ViewPackOne) {
                    return new FragmentOne();
                }
            case 1:
                if(ViewPackOne){
                    return new FragmentTwo();
                }
            case 2:
                if(ViewPackOne) {
                    return new FragmentThree();
                }

            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }

    public static class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two_layout, container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentThree extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly? currently I am complete blank with ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FragmentActivity is a sub class of activity so it also has the **startActivity()** method

Suppose we want to start ActivityB from a **Fragment**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And to start it from the **FragmentActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: So basically start a new activity. yet there are more fragments to come, that is why the if statements are there in the Fragment getItem.  Also, how  do I start this whole fragment packs from a new activity?

Comment: @Davey Each `FragmentActivity` has its own `Fragments` **independent** on the **other** `FragmentActivity` where it's being started from, so you can start one from the other and so on

Comment: Alright it's working now besides it isn't loading the fragments.  Might that because it's a sub class in a class?

Comment: @Davey I don't expect that to happen if every thing is setup correctly.If you are starting another FragmentActivity,it should also have it's own **FragmentPagerManager** and **Adapter** independent of the first one and it's fragments should load fine.

Comment: me again.   Yes I tried to use FragmentActivity only, but sadly it doesn't have an FragmentPagerAdapter for me.  Also it returns only 1 blank fragment

Comment: @Davey As I said earlier,try using AppCompatActivity instead fo FragmentActivity

Comment: I reinstalled the open source and AppCompatActivity has fragmentmanager now.    But as for now, I am still new to Android developement, so I have no clue how to let this FragmentManager use getItem(int arg0) by using AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @Davey Great if it works,check out this link for more about Fragments and the FragmentPagerAdapter https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: @Davey And http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Everything is working now, thanks lad. You have just saved my sanity from dying!